# Hashing Similar Strings to same Hash Value

Tags: hash, similarity

Is there some hashing algorithm that can hash similar text documents to a particular Hash Value ?

For example,

A = "This is Sample Text 1"
B=  "This is Sample Text 2"

A and B need to be hashed to a same value.

I have done a bit of research and read about SimHash and LSH algorithms.
Simhash causes hash collisions and similarity can be defined by using hamming distance.

Ideally I want something like " If String A and String B differ by a acceptable threshold of similarity (t < tmax), hash A and B to a same hash value."

Comment: I am not sure that there would be a way. I remember from a "properties of good hash functions" article I read somewhere, that one such property is that similar values do not yield similar hashes, so that any structural similarities in the data (which is common in real life data) is not reflected in the hash, and therefore items are distributed evenly throughout the hash table.

Comment: HI Tom, yes a property of a Good Hash is not to yield similar hashes. But there are algorithms desinged specifically to cause collisions. The SimHash algorithm is an example of one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An obvious option is to use [Soundex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soundex) or one of its variants (depending on the language of these words).

You didn't specify what you need this for.

- If you need to create some sort of hashtable variant, where you place similar strings in the same bucket, soundex variants could work, but you need to take the possibility that you could have collisions into account.
- If you only need some indication of how similar two strings are, you can also look at an algorithm called Simil; see [this link](http://www.accessmvp.com/tomvanstiphout/simil.htm), or spell checking related algorithms.

Comment: Yes, So basically what I am hoping to do is this 1) Hash Similar items to the same bucket 2) For a new string, from a data stream, do a look up, if it is found, consider it as near duplicate and ignore them